# Expression for maximum energy transfer to electron by fast moving charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-electrodynamics

Suppose a charge $q = +Z e$ is moving along positive $+x$ direction with electron below $x-$axis and the charge is moving fast enough to consider electron at rest, then what is the maximum value of energy that is transferred to electron?

According to my note,

> "it can be showed that $E_{max} = 2m\gamma^2 v^2$ "

where $\gamma$ is Lorentz factor and $v, m$ are velocity and mass of the charge. My note is probably based on J.D. Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics. I haven't read that whole book. But as far as I know, such results are not derived on that book. How do I arrive at above result.

So far, I know, energy transfer can be calculated as 
$$\Delta E = \frac{2 Z^2 e^4}{mb^2v^2}$$
where $b$ is impact parameter. As $b \to 0, \Delta E \to \infty$, the original problem is to find the bounds for $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with a collision between two particles. Particle 1 has mass $m_1$, momentum $\mathbf{p}_{\rm lab}$, and total energy $E_{\rm lab}$ while Particle 2 (mass $m_2$) is stationary. Particle 1 then scatters off at an angle $\psi$ while particle 2 scatters off in angle $\zeta$. By using a transformation of coordinates, we can jump into a frame in which it would appear that the two particles are coming towards each other at the same speed (center of mass (c.m.) frame)

[image]

([source](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/newton/node52.html))

It's often convenient to work in the c.m. frame, so we'll use that.

It can be shown that the total energy in the c.m. frame is given by
$$
W^2=m_1^2+m_2^2+2m_2E_{\rm lab}\tag{1}
$$
The change in energy for Particle 2 is then given by
$$
\Delta E=\frac{m_2}{W^2}p^2_{\rm lab}\left(1-\cos\theta\right)=\frac{m_2}{m_1^2+m_2^2+2m_2E_{\rm lab}}p^2_{\rm lab}\left(1-\cos\theta\right)\tag{2}
$$
In order to find the maximum energy transfer, we need to do a little hokey business. First is an easy one: 
$$\left(1-\cos\theta\right)_{max}=2\quad({\rm at}\,\,\theta=\pi)$$
Next, we use the relation $p=\gamma\beta m$ and assume that $m_1\gg m_2$ so that $W\simeq m_1$. Equation (2) then becomes
$$
\Delta E_{max}\simeq\frac{m_2}{m_1^2}\cdot\gamma^2\beta^2m_1^2\cdot2
$$
The $m_1^2$ terms cancel leaving the expected relation:
$$
\Delta E_{max}\simeq2m_2\gamma^2\beta^2
$$

Comment: As an aside: This is effectively Problem 11.26 from Jackson's 3rd Edition.

Comment: $m$ in my expression was mass of second particle ... which i assumed first particle. looks okay.

Comment: @MulaKoSaag: The necessary assumption is that $m_1\gg m_2$, so we assume that $m_1$ is an ion and $m_2$ the electron. But the $\gamma$ and $\beta$ values are for $m_1$

Comment: yeah I noted that ... there is a numerical problem exactly based on it, the $m$ is replaced by mass of electron. I suppose I should leave the question unedited.